# C declare an array for a struct inside a struct

Tags: arrays, c, struct

So I have something like this:

```
struct cat{
    int breed;
    enum state status;
    ...    

    struct{
        int catNumber;
        ...
    } feederOperations[MAX_FEEDER];
}cats[MAX_CATS];
```

Don't worry if the code deosn't make sense, all I'm wondering is how should/ can I declare a new 1d array of the inside structure?

Comment: hmmm? You just did.

Comment: I mean if I need a separate one in another function? Also isn't that sort of like a 2d array so it's tied to cats[]? or can I call for feederOperations[] just treating it like a normal 1d array? @ikegami

Comment: @PapaSheng You can declare as many as you like, using the same syntax you're using for `feederOperations` or any other data type you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you remove the anonymous of the inner structure and give it a name.

There is no special scoping rules for inner structures in C which means that the scope of `struct cat` is the same as the scope of `struct feederOp`.

```
struct cat{
    int breed;
    enum state status;
    ...    

    struct feederOp {
        int catNumber;
        ...
    } feederOperations[MAX_FEEDER];
}cats[MAX_CATS];
```

Thus you can create variable of type `struct feederOp` wherever you need as below.

```
struct feederOp var1;
```